# How do I hide the toolbar in Full Screen mode in TeamViewer?

Tags: teamviewer

I use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) to remote into some computers and it's just fine. The only thing is the big annoying toolbar at the top of the screen that prevents me from accessing the menubar in the current application if it's in full-screen mode.  Is there a way to hide that toolbar in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a small tab dropping down from the right side of the toolbar. The far right button on it, looking like `^`, hides the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

This is a supplement to SaintWacko's great answer since images cannot be included in comments.
This is the button meant by the answer:

[image]

This is what it looks like after the toolbar is hidden:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to minimize this by default?